# Flex BubbleChart - how to make the maximum bubble size half of what it currently is?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, charts, flex4

I'm trying to control the actual pixel size of the bubbles on BubbleChart with no success. The bubbles are always about 2 to 50 pixels no matter what I set the minRadius and maxRadius values to.

Here is the code:

```
    <mx:BubbleChart width="100%" height="200" dataProvider="{dataSet}">
        <mx:series>
            <mx:BubbleSeries radiusField="P" 
                             showDataEffect="{eff}" 
                             xField="A" 
                             yField="B"
                             minRadius="0"
                             maxRadius="10">
            </mx:BubbleSeries>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:BubbleChart>
```

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I needed to set the minRadius and maxRadius on the BubbleChart not on the Series

```
    <mx:BubbleChart width="100%" height="200"
                    minRadius="10" maxRadius="20"
                    dataProvider="{dataSet}">
        <mx:series>
            <mx:BubbleSeries radiusField="P" 
                             showDataEffect="{eff}" 
                             xField="A" 
                             yField="B">
            </mx:BubbleSeries>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:BubbleChart>
```